# How to merge csv files based on unique columns in java

Tags: java, opencsv

I have 3 different very large files and my requirement is to merge them together in one single csv file. All these 3 files have different number of columns but they contain some unique column between each other.

**Example**
file 1:

```
StudentId   StudentName   ClassId
1           Ajay           6
2           Vinay          8
3           Geeta          6
4           Sameer         7
```

file 2:

```
ClassId       ClassColor
6           Blue
7           Grey
8           White
```

file 3:

```
HouseId    HouseName    StudentId
1          Knights       4
2          Spartans      1
3          Samurai       2
4          Trojans       3
```

As you can see file1 and file2 has classId in common And file1 and file2 has studentId in common.
Now based on this information I want have result like this by joining files based on common key.

```
StudentId     StudentName    ClassId     ClassColor    HouseId    HouseName
1             Ajay           6           Blue          2          Spartans
2             Vinay          8           White         3          Samurai
3             Geeta          6           Blue          4          Trojans
4             Sameer         7           Grey          1          Knights
```

This scenario is completely new to me, I did some research but didn't find solution for it in java.

Comment: Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @gurudas-k-s Please demonstrate your effort to solve problem first

Comment: There no magic solution for problems like this in Java, or in any programming language (unless you count SQL, I guess). Broadly you'll have to read and parse the input files, and store the data in some format you can manage. Then you'll need to merge this stored data into some combined format. Then you'll need to write out the merged data into a new file. These are all standard programming tasks, but require a fair amount of coding work. If you're looking for a pre-packaged solution, I doubt you'll find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage I am able to join two files with below implementation:

Class to hold csv file data:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class CsvVo {
    private Map<String, String> keyVal;
    public CsvVo(String id) {
        keyVal = new LinkedHashMap<>();// you may also use HashMap if you don't need to keep order
    }

    public Map<String, String> getKeyVal() {
        return keyVal;
    }
    public void setKeyVal(Map<String, String> keyVal) {
        this.keyVal = keyVal;
    }
    public void put(String key, String val) {
        keyVal.put(key, val);
    }
    public String get(String key) {
        return keyVal.get(key);
    }
}
```

CSV parser to read files:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
public class CsvParser {
    public static List<CsvVo> getRecodrsFromACsv(File file, List<String> keys) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<CsvVo> records = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isHeader = true;
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (isHeader) {// first line is header
                isHeader = false;
                continue;
            }
            CsvVo record = new CsvVo(file.getName());
            String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
                record.put(keys.get(i), lineSplit[i]);
            }
            records.add(record);
        }
        br.close();
        return records;
    }
    public static List<String> getHeadersFromACsv(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> headers = null;
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
            headers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(lineSplit));
            break;
        }
        br.close();
        return headers;
    }
    public static void writeToCsv(final File file, final Set<String> headers, final List<CsvVo> records)
            throws IOException {
        FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        // write headers
        String sep = "";
        String[] headersArr = headers.toArray(new String[headers.size()]);
        for (String header : headersArr) {
            csvWriter.append(sep);
            csvWriter.append(header);
            sep = ",";
        }
        csvWriter.append("\n");
        // write records at each line
        for (CsvVo record : records) {
            sep = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < headersArr.length; i++) {
                csvWriter.append(sep);
                csvWriter.append(record.get(headersArr[i]));
                sep = ",";
            }
            csvWriter.append("\n");
        }
        csvWriter.flush();
        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Main Class to test the functionality:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class CsvApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File csv1 = new File("/Users/guru/Desktop/Standard.csv");
        File csv2 = new File("/Users/guru/Desktop/Match.csv");
        List<String> csv1Headers = CsvParser.getHeadersFromACsv(csv1);
        //csv1Headers.forEach(h -> System.out.print(h + " "));
        //System.out.println();
        List<String> csv2Headers = CsvParser.getHeadersFromACsv(csv2);
        //csv2Headers.forEach(h -> System.out.print(h + " "));
        //System.out.println();
        List<String> allCsvHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
        allCsvHeaders.addAll(csv1Headers);
        allCsvHeaders.addAll(csv2Headers);
        //allCsvHeaders.forEach(h -> System.out.print(h + " "));
        //System.out.println();
        Set<String> uniqueHeaders = new HashSet<>(allCsvHeaders);
        //uniqueHeaders.forEach(h -> System.out.print(h + " "));
        //System.out.println();
        List<CsvVo> csv1Records = CsvParser.getRecodrsFromACsv(csv1, csv1Headers);
        List<CsvVo> csv2Records = CsvParser.getRecodrsFromACsv(csv2, csv2Headers);
        List<CsvVo> allCsvRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        String key = "StudentID";
        getUniqueRecordsForKey(key, csv1Records, csv2Records,allCsvRecords);
       // allCsvRecords.addAll(csv1Records);
        //allCsvRecords.addAll(csv2Records);
        CsvParser.writeToCsv(new File("/Users/guru/Desktop/Output.csv"), uniqueHeaders, allCsvRecords);
    }

    private static void getUniqueRecordsForKey(String key, List<CsvVo> csv1Records, List<CsvVo> csv2Records, List<CsvVo> allCsvRecords) {

        for (CsvVo record1: csv1Records){
            for(CsvVo record2: csv2Records){
                if( !record1.getKeyVal().get(key).isEmpty() && record1.getKeyVal().get(key).equals(record2.getKeyVal().get(key))){
                    HashMap<String ,String> mergedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
                    CsvVo mergedRecord = new CsvVo(record2.getKeyVal().get(key));
                    mergeRecords(mergedMap, record1,record2);
                    mergedRecord.setKeyVal(mergedMap);
                    csv2Records.remove(record2);
                    allCsvRecords.add(mergedRecord);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void mergeRecords(HashMap mergedMap,CsvVo record1, CsvVo record2 ){
        mergedMap.putAll(record1.getKeyVal());
        mergedMap.putAll(record2.getKeyVal());
    }
}
```

Here we are loading entire data of files to lists and then comparing data based on the column we want to join. In this case i have taken StudentID.

Not sure if this is good approach for big files.

Comment: Above solution is just to merge two file. This process can be repeated for joining multiple file. Just read the output file and merge it with third file.